# Facebook Account kit Giving Error Authentication failed

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-account-kit

When after entering mobile number on account kit popup it told me that We're sorry, something went wrong. and I get :

```
response.status = NOT_AUTHENTICATED
```

**Code ::-**

```
<div onclick="phone_btn_onclick();" class="btn btn-info text-center">Verify mobile number
          </div>

<script>
var mobile_veri=false;
// initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        appId:1066226316760891,         
        state:"abcd", 
        version:"v1.0"
      }
    );
  };
  function loginCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
       mobile_veri=true;
    }
    else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
      // handle authentication failure
      console.log("Authentication failure");
    }
    else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
      // handle bad parameters
      console.log("Bad parameters");
    }
  }
   function phone_btn_onclick() {
    var country_code = document.getElementById("country_code").value;
    var ph_num = document.getElementById("phone_num").value;
    AccountKit.login('PHONE', 
      {countryCode: country_code,phoneNumber: ph_num}, // will use default values if this is not specified
      loginCallback);
  }
  function email_btn_onclick() {  
    // you can add emailAddress to set value
    AccountKit.login('EMAIL', {}, loginCallback);
  }
  // destroying session
  function logout() {
        document.location = '/logout';
  }
</script>
```

ACCOUNT KIT JAVASCRIPT CODE:

[image]

App/Account Kit in my Facebook Developer Dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Please post the whole code here, not links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added code.

Comment: You can try adding debug:true in the init function to see more descriptive error messages

Comment: https://youtu.be/o2-PCiiJzr4 - This video explains integration from creating facebook app to validate it in serverside, with code samples in github.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?